# Weird font awesome rendering when used in hyperlink

Tags: fonts, fontawesome, hyperlink, href

When I add a `\href` to a `fontawesome` icon, it becomes very distorted. It works fine without it. For example,

```
\documentclass[]{awesome-cv}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\href{url_here}{\faGithub}

\begin{document}
\begin{cventries}
    \cventry
    {}
    {Title \href{url_here}{{\faGithub} }}
    {}
    {}
    {\begin{cvitems}
        \item {}}
    \end{cvitems}}
\end{cventries}
\end{document}
```

produces this, with weird cutoffs on the side:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It works fine for me with `\href{https://www.github.com}{\faGithub}` in a standard document. You have not shown only a single line, but not the the minimal document that generates this issue. Also the pdf viewer could be responsible for this and the rendering could be improved by zooming in.

Comment: Do you by any chance have white link borders enabled? That could explain what you see. Anyway, we can only help you properly if we can see a complete example document that reproduces what you see, a so-called MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). Please also mention if you compile your document with pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: I have added in a ME. I am compiling with XeLaTex. I don't think its the white link borders since I don't see this issue with world links, only icons.

Comment: I can't get your MWE to work because there are a great many unrelated errors, but I can reproduce a similar issue if I compile `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,fontawesome}
\usepackage[allbordercolors=white]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\href{url_here}{\faGithub}
\end{document}` (only with XeLaTeX, the other engines are fine).

Comment: Thank you for noticing that! I changed it to LuaTaTeX and it seems to be working fine now.

Comment: Please also tell us which version of the template you are loading. A very old version uses `allbordercolors=white`, but newer versions use `hidelinks` (https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV/commit/8cad64c33750265bb0df7b3da5c9970969d0a85f)

Comment: Sorry, I am new to Latex. How can I find out which template I am loading?